# jsp cannot resolve variable

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, jstl

Im learning about jsp/servlets and I,ve got simple problem with Intellij.
Its just simple program, no need for explanation i think..

https://github.com/carrothead/mvc_course.git

and the problem is here: 
it says that variable cannot be resolved, 
i try to write sth like  items="${requestScope.names}"
[link to problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAhlC.png)

ive tried to change tomcat version, create new project or add new jst lib but nothing works..

Comment: Have you setted the atributte in the request in the servlet? `request.setAttribute("studentList", strings);`

Comment: request.setAttribute("names", strings); i think foreach should be   `<c:forEach items="${names}" var="e">`

Comment: every line of code is just like you told me, just look no github... its not working... now i see that the guy from course is running servlet class not jsp but i Intellj i cannot run servlet class..